# Setting form value to C# Variable

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have a basic entry form, I need to set the entryDate field to todays date automatically so that when the user hits submit, the database will autofill with todays date (As a string)

```
<input for="EntryDate" value=@entryDate class="form-control" bind="@ath.EntryDate"/>

@functions{
    EventAthlete ath = new EventAthlete();

    string entryDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

    protected async Task AddAthlete()
    {
        await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/Athlete/Add", ath);

    }
}
```

I would expect from the above code that it would autofill the form with my `entryDate` variable?

Or better yet is there a way instead of saying that `ath.Entrydate` is bound to that form, is it possible to set `ath.Entrydate` automatically in my `Functions@{}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition, if you're using at least C# 6.0, you can default the initialization value of the property.

```
public DateTime EntryDate { get; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Can confirm this does work in .Net core 2.1 and decided to go this route.

Comment: You could also do `public DateTime EntryDate => DateTime.Now;`

Comment: @Chris Right, which is exactly what William is using.

Comment: @AustinWBryan I'm not saying you're wrong, just adding to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Create a default constructor for EventAthlete and set the entryDate property to today's date.

```
public class EventAthlete
{
    public DateTime entryDate { get; set; }
    public EventAthlete() => entryDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Hey!!! My man this worked haha I actually did DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() since my datafield is a string.

Comment: Quick question, If I want to add another default value, would I simply add that property to the default constructor, or make another?

Comment: You should really create another question, but its a similar approach. Create the property in the class, assign it in the default constructor.